# How can I implement a columns UI using React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm talking about the UI as seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86J6J.png). In that program, macOS Finder, you have a column on the left, which lists all the items inside a directory. If you click an item, and that item is itself a directory, a new column opens on the right containing all *its* entries, and this repeats forever.

I'd like to write a UI like this using React for a simple text-editing web application. Each column would contain folders or text 'files'. Clicking a folder would open that folder's children in the next column over; clicking a text 'file' would place its text in a textarea element for reading or editing.

But I can't figure out how to structure the data.

I think I'd want a sort of tree, where nodes can be either text-files or folders/trees themselves. But how would I then render that tree in React, what pattern of components could I use? Would I render the top level of the current tree into one column component, and have an onclick handler in that component that adds a new column to the parent if a subfolder gets clicked? And if so, would I pass that component some reference to a sub-part of the tree, or pass over the entire portion of that tree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the material UI Menu component. It lets you have subMenus as well

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu